# Sails.js + Grunt "Cannot find module" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I'm trying to run sails.js in Win7 Starter on a netbook.  When I execute 'sails lift' I do get my desired web page at port:1337 but the style files are not being linked to it.  The linking is supposed to be done by Grunt.js but it throws the error below.  I interpret the error as follow: Grunt is truncating the user path that should read 'c:\Users\Harry Roach...' to 'c:\Users\Harry'.  If that interpretation is correct, how can I work around it?  Note that sails.js working seems completely dependent on Grunt working i.e. a single point of failure, so a Grunt upgrade is broken sails.js is broken.  Is that correct?

[SOLVED] As per Stackoverflow question 20068270 - Install sails.js *locally* and/or avoid any spaces in directory names. And, yes, Grunt is a single point of failure in sails.js.

```
$ sails lift
error: Grunt ::
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\Harry'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

info:
info:
info:    Sails.js           <|
info:    v0.9.4              |\
```

Comment: probably need an escape for the space character in the path

Comment: I haven't specified that path, it seems to be set during sails.js install.  Is there a config file that contains the path?

Comment: how do you have grunt installed? Are you sure you have a local copy of grunt in your node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes, there is a copy of grunt in node-modules folder (also ejs, optimist, sails-disk).

Comment: Can you share your Gruntfile?

Comment: Question edited to show 'Gruntfile.js'.

Comment: Could relate to this similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068270/space-creates-a-throw-err-in-module-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Stackoverflow question 20068270 - Install sails.js locally and/or avoid any spaces in directory names. And, yes, Grunt is a single point of failure in sails.js.